# Set the site display language based on browser's default language

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have my site in two languages i.e. English and French, I want that whenever a user visits the site, it must be displayed in the browser's default language. How to do it ?

Comment: You can do this with Locale. Set your language as default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Admin -> Module -> Locale
2. Click on Configuration (Locale)
3. Enable Radio button as per you want to set default language.

Comment: Then it will be set as default language of my site, but I want that according to browser's default language the display language must change

Comment: You mean that If browser default language is French then site open in french language ?

Comment: Yes, Exactly...

Comment: Have you check the site by changing the browser laguage ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this:

- create a module (theme independant) that inserts some javascript into the page
- using php, insert the current site language into the javascript as a variable
- check the browser language against the site current language
- if it matches, nothing happens, if not, create a redirect to mysite.com/fr/ or however you have it setup to differentiate the languages